# Authentication credentials were not provided. when deployed to AWS

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

I created some APIs on the Django project using Django rest framework.
I set IsAdminUser to permission classes.

When I run the project locally and make a request to it with auth info, it works.

I deployed it to AWS server by using Elastic Beanstalk and make a request, and it returns error 403

```
Authentication credentials were not provided
```

Here is my API

```
class HamListApiView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Ham.objects.all()
    serializer_class = HamSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAdminUser]
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: how did you sent the request?

Comment: I used python 'Requests' to make requests

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My guess is that the server does not allow authorization header.

Usual issue with aws beanstalk

Try to add this to your container commands:

```
 01_wsgipass:
     command: 'echo "WSGIPassAuthorization On" >> ../wsgi.conf'
```

Comment: Did work!  You saved me a lot of time and thank you!

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. I was getting the following error when I tried using the above code https://pasteboard.co/I4DxyC8.png. I tried adding the code as in this link http://collabedit.com/vkygw it doesn't work. Any inputs on this, please.

Comment: life saver! Thanks for posting this.